# Separar as informações do XML

Tags: php

como eu faria para separar as questões conforme a disciplina de um arquivo xml no PHP? Ex.: Matemática resposta c, d e a...FIsica resposta c,d e E

```
<disciplina nome="Matemática">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>

      <disciplina nome="Física">
         <questao numero="1" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>C</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="2" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>D</resposta>
         </questao>
         <questao numero="3" alternativas="A,B,C,D,E">
            <resposta>A</resposta>
         </questao>
      </disciplina>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use essa função para passar de xml para uma array em php

Vou fazer um update da função, pois encontrei um metodo de uma classe que não está aqui disponível. Então agora ela está completa.

---

```
/*
This function goes to the directory $pathDir, pass trough each all files inside it,
seeks for any file that math to the $searchString and reads it.
Return the content of all matched xml files within a php Array.
Ex: 
We have inside the FTP the follow files genereted by a CronJob: 
fileCarAudiRent2015.xml, fileCarAudiRent2016.xml, fileCarAudiSell2015.xm,
fileCarBMWRent2015.xml, fileCarBMWSell2016.xml, fileBoatWMBRent2015.xml, fileBoatWMBSell2015.xml,
fileBoatAudiRent2015.xml, fileBoatAudiSell2016.xml, ... .

We want to grab the content of all files that matches "Boat" string.
So, we need to do like this:
$arrInfo = read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll("c:/Path_to_the_Folder","Boat");

We want to grab the content of all files that matches "Sell2015" string.
So, we need to do like this:
$arrInfo = read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll("c:/Path_to_the_Folder","Sell2015");

We should inprove this function to match criteria like:
Give me all that has Sell AND 2015
Give me all that has Sell OR 2015
...
Give me all that has BMW AND 2015
*/


public function read_XML_from_Folder_return_arrayAll($pathDir,$searchString) {

$xml_array="";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($pathDir); //http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
  if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
      $fileName = $fileinfo->getFilename();
      //Macth rule
      $pos = strpos($fileName, $searchString);
      if ( $pos!== false) {//If match the sought string
        $filePath = $pathDir.$fileName;
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
            $xml_array [] = unserialize(serialize(json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1)));  

           /* If needed 
           $invoice_date = $xml_array["Documents"]["InvoiceDate"];
           $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $invoice_date);//Formated date inside xml
           $year = $date->format('Y');//Desired output year
           $month = $date->format('M');//Desired output month 
           */

      }//End of if ( $pos!== false)                        
  } 
}
//Testing
echo "<pre>";
  print_r($xml_array);
echo "</pre>";


return $xml_array;

 }
```

Depois fica fácil. Faça um loop na sua array php e filtre dentro do loop.
[Fonte](https://gist.github.com/igoralves1?page=1)

Comment: Funcionou... obrigado zwitterion